# How to get row of floated images inside a div element to resize with browser window

Tags: html, css

I have been unable to figure out how to get four images inside a div to resize when the browser window is resized. Right now, when the browser window becomes too small the last image on the left moves to the next row, which I don't want to happen. I want the images to stay in one row. I have looked at many suggestions here and elsewhere online and tried and tried and I can't figure it out! It may be relevant to know that I have the max-width of all the images at 24% because the original images are too big for my purposes. Also,  I have a div around the entire body of the page to set the max-width of the body at 1900px and the min-width at 700px.  Here is the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<br>
<div id="contain">
<img src="webphoto6.jpg" alt="Mary" class="one">
<img src="webphoto3.jpg" alt="Mary" class="two">
<img src="webphoto42.jpg" alt="Mary" class="three">
<img src="WebPhoto.jpg" alt="Mary" class="four">
</div>
<div id="clearfix">
<br>
```

CSS:

```
#contain { max-width: 1900px; 
min-width: 780px;
display: block; 
}
img { width: auto;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; 
}
.one {float: left;
max-width: 24%;
max-height: auto;
padding-right:20px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px; 
}
.two {float: left;
max-width: 24%;
max-height: auto;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px; 
}
.three { float: left;
max-width: 24%;
max-height: auto;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px; 
}
.four {float: left;
max-width: 24%;
max-height: auto;
padding: 0px; 
margin: 0px;
}
#clearfix {clear: both;}
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the fixed padding of 20px. Try using a percentage here too, for example padding:0.24%

Comment: YES! That fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept my answer, that would make me happy!! :)